# VB.Net Installation and DLL horrors

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, installation

have been working and wearing out my fingers doing google searches with this one:

I generally develop on server side, but we require small desktop apps to connect certain hardware pieces with our web based software -- I put something together with very limited knowledge of VB.Net no issues there. I don't know much about making installers, messing with the registry or signing programs to make antivirus software not flag my executables as unsafe.

My main woe is that I have a DLL file I used for my installation which I don't know how to register during the installation process. I am using VB.Net Express 2010 for the actual application code and InnoIDE to compile an installation script with those files.

Is there a script I can add to InnoIDE so it will register the DLL file for me? Or is this something I can do programmatically from VB.Net (Express version, not full...). The DLL is a COM library, so according to the research I did it requires registering.

As an aside, any information anyone could provide in terms of signing the application or something which will stop antivirus software from warning users that this file could be potentially unsafe? We use Avast in the office and in all test machines Avast tried to have the app run in the sandbox every time I ran it.

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if this question requires further information.

Comment: Try looking at this [Technet article about Regsrvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I know about regsvr32 and am using it on the development machine. My problem is that I am unsure of how to set up the installer to register this DLL on installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since InnoIDE is just a graphical interface to Inno Setup you could try using the Pascal Scripting function [RegisterServer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_registerserver.htm).

From above link

> Registers the DLL/OCX with the specified filename. If Is64Bit is True,
>   the DLL/OCX will be loaded as a 64-bit image and registered in a
>   64-bit process. If FailCriticalErrors is True, the system will not
>   display any critical-error-handler message boxes. Raises an exception
>   if not successful.

Comment: God, that explains why my searches were not really resulting in much... I was searching for InnoIDE instead of InnoSetup for documentation!

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No Problem, happy to have been able to help